# How to read resourcefile from dll c#

Tags: c#, resource-files

I would like to use resourcefiles to get some text.These resourcefiles will be in dll.It's nothing todo with localization just in case you ask.
I want to have the ability to choose which rexfile to use based on a configsettings.

Sample
MyCompany.RexFiles.dll

1. RexFileA
2. RexFileB
3. RexFileC

My question 
Given that in a config file I have a settings that decide which rexfile to use eg CurrentRexfile="RexFileB"

How can I default to right rexFile depending on the configSettings.

Any suggestions

Comment: Perhaps some advanced reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ResourceManager Class to retrieve resources:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly myAssembly = this.GetType().Assembly;

string rexFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CuurentRexfile"];
System.Reflection.Assembly otherAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(rexFile);

System.Resources.ResourceManager resManager = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("ResourceNamespace.myResources", otherAssembly);

string test = resManager.GetString("resourceString");
```

more read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984408(VS.71).aspx)

Comment: thanks for your reply.Would that work using attributes ,I mean calling "resManager.GetString("resourceString") within an attribute.I wish it could be wrapped up to get called like resources.MyName-resources.MySurname etc...

Comment: sorry, now I am confused, don't know what attribute you mean.